# Is the phrase "to withdraw money from one account to another" correct?

Tags: phrase-usage

I know I can say:
**(1)** *I want to withdraw $100 from my bank account*.

But I'm interested in whether the verb "withdraw" can be used with the place where the money will come to. For example:
**(2)** *I want to withdraw $100 from one of my bank accounts **to my other bank account***.
**(3)** *I want to withdraw $100 from my Google wallet **to my PayPal wallet***.
Or just:
**(4)** *I want to withdraw $100 **to my new bank account***.

So, are (2), (3) and (4) correct?

Comment: It’s fine for me.

Comment: No, you are describing a funds' transfer. 2, 3 and 4 are incorrect.  You might look up some of this stuff.

Answer (score 4):

The word used for this is "transfer":

> I want to transfer £100 from one of my bank accounts to my other bank account.

> I want to transfer £100 to my new bank account.

<sub>This is [british-english](/questions/tagged/british-english) but I'm not aware that Americans use a different term.</sub>

Comment: "Transfer" is also the correct word to use in American English. If you want to use "withdraw", you have to also use "deposit": I want to withdraw $100 and deposit it in my new bank account.

Comment: AmE is exactly the same. And yes, withdrawing money and transferring money are two different things.

Answer (score 3):

While all of these are comprehensible, we don't usually use it this way when "withdraw" is transitive. James' suggestion of "transfer" is the most efficient; if one insists on "withdraw," it would usually be paired with "deposit": "I withdrew $100 from Account A and deposited it into Account B."

But note, people can "withdraw to" a place, usually as a retreat, as from stress or when describing military maneuvers. E.g. "the monks withdrew to their monastery," or "the cavalry withdrew to the other side of the river." It's not a usage we would have cause to use often, and note it doesn't have anything to do with transitive uses in which we "withdraw *something*."